# spring boot: cannot read resource inside flat jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable-jar, embedded-resource

I can't read a resource file inside spring flat file.
I've put my resource file inside
`src/main/resources`
folder, and then in my `@Component` class:
`@Value("classpath:Graphic.xlsx") private Resource excelTemplateFile;`

It works if I run my app using:
`mvn spring-boot:run`
but if I build my flat jar:
`mvn package`

`java -jar target\myapp-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`

and I run it, IT does not work!

The result is surprising:
`11:07:18.894 ERROR - class path resource [Graphic.xlsx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Users/hp/Projects/myApp/target/myapp-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/Graphic.xlsx`

It is surprising because the file is exactly included in the jar file in that position (myapp-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/Graphic.xlsx)

So, why?
I'm trying to use ResourceUtils, or read it in other ways, but the result is the same.
How can I solve it?
thx.

Environment:
windows 64 bit.

java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)

Spring boot:
Pom parent : spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.7
spring dependencies:  spring-shell-starter 2.1.0 and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: Please don't forget to `clean` ..and this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-repackage-vs-mvn-package

Comment: does not work, spring repackage is ok, but the result is the same. I mean, the file exists in the jar file, and in the right position! more over I've tried to put @Value("classpath*:Graphic.xlsx")
    private Resource excelTemplateFile; 
But still not work. I suppose it is a problem with the JVM  (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86) because I can remember that with very old JVMs , this approach has always worked very well.

Comment: Did you exclude.xlsx extensions in the maven jar plugin when you were building the jar?

Comment: Hi Rasika, I checked the content of the jar file and It Is correct.